# How to get file parent parent's folder using batch

Tags: for-loop, batch-file

Im using batch below to generate a CSV report from multiple .LOG files in 3 Station folders. The code works perfectly to generate report but I want parent folder (Station number folder not the TAG folder) in the report too.

**Batch file located at:**

```
C:\Users\amein\Google Drive\Report BACKUP
```

**LOG file path:**

```
C:\Users\amein\Google Drive\Report BACKUP\Station1\TAG\10092019.LOG
C:\Users\amein\Google Drive\Report BACKUP\Station2\TAG\10092019.LOG
C:\Users\amein\Google Drive\Report BACKUP\Station3\TAG\10092019.LOG
```

```
@echo off
cls
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /a total=0
type NUL>"Report.csv"
(
    for /R "C:\Users\amein\Google Drive\Report BACKUP\" %%f in (*.LOG) do (
        for /f %%a in ('type "%%f"^|find /C /v  "" ') do set /a total+=%%a&echo %%f , %%~nf , %%a
    )
    echo total , !total!
)>>"Report.csv"

GOTO :EOF
```

edit: **SOLVED**

```
@echo off
cls
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /a total=0
type NUL>Report.csv
(
echo Station Number,Date ,Done
 for /R "%userprofile%\Google Drive\Report BACKUP\" %%G in (*.LOG) do (
  for %%b in ("%%~dpG\.\..") do set station= %%~nxb
  for /f %%a in ('type "%%G"^|find /C /v  "" ') do set /a total+=%%a&echo !station!,%%~nG ,%%a
 )

 echo ,TOTAL ,!total!
)>>Report.csv

GOTO :EOF
```

Is it possible? I want the report in CSV only show the station number instead of full path

```
Station 1 10092019 100
```

Comment: Try the command line `for %%I in ("%%~dpf..") do echo Station folder is: %%~fI` as first line of outer `for` for full path and `for %%I in ("%%~dpf..") do echo Station folder is: %%~nxI` for just `Station 1`, `Station 2`, ... Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/) window, run `for /?` and read the output help. Then you should also know why `f` is not the best choice as loop variable. I recommend further to replace `C:\Users\amein` by `%UserProfile%`.

Comment: Hint: The path string referenced with `%%~dpG` ends always with a backslash. For that reason `%%~dpG` should not be concatenated with one more backslash with a file/folder path/name. ``.\`` is completely useless in the string `%%~dpG\.\..`. All you really need is `%%~dpG..` which expands to `C:\Users\amein\Google Drive\Report BACKUP\Station1\TAG\..` on execution which is exactly what you need to reference `C:\Users\amein\Google Drive\Report BACKUP\Station1`.

Comment: PS: You could use also `for %%b in ("%%~dpG..") do for /f %%a in ('type "%%G" ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /C /v "" ') do set /a "total+=%%a" & echo %%~nxb,%%~nG ,%%a`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
cls
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /a total=0
type NUL>Report.csv
(
echo Station Number,Date ,Done
 for /R "%userprofile%\Google Drive\Report BACKUP\" %%G in (*.LOG) do (
  for %%b in ("%%~dpG\.\..") do set station= %%~nxb
  for /f %%a in ('type "%%G"^|find /C /v  "" ') do set /a total+=%%a&echo !station!,%%~nG ,%%a
 )

 echo ,TOTAL ,!total!
)>>Report.csv

GOTO :EOF
```