# Change date format from file name (ddmmyyyy) into dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: batch-file

Following from previous code, [previous link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57972590/how-to-get-file-parent-parents-folder-using-batch?noredirect=1#comment102382862_57972590) I would like to improvise my code by changing date format which is ddmmyyyy which I get from file name then stored this data into CSV file.
Is it easier to change from file name or inside csv file?

File name

```
10092019.LOG
11092019.LOG
12092019.LOG
```

Current code

```
@echo off
cls
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /a total=0
type NUL>Report.csv
(
echo Station Number,Date ,Done
 for /R "%userprofile%\Google Drive\Report BACKUP\" %%G in (*.LOG) do (
  for %%b in ("%%~dpG\.\..") do set station= %%~nxb
  for /f %%a in ('type "%%G"^|find /C /v  "" ') do set /a total+=%%a&echo !station!,%%~nG ,%%a
 )

 echo ,TOTAL ,!total!
)>>Report.csv

GOTO :EOF
```

CSV file format contain 2 header

```
LASTEST UPDATE: 27/Sep/2019 12:26 , ,
STATION NUMBER,DATE ,TAG
 Station1,10092019 ,11
 Station1,11092019 ,491
 Station1,12092019 ,205
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the idea from [here](https://www.computerhope.com/forum/index.php?topic=68776.0) while looking for a solution. Silly me all I need to do is just adding this 2 line..

```
set dt= %%~nG
```

and

```
echo !dt:~0,3!/!dt:~3,2!/!dt:~5,8!
```

but Im still open for a suggestion or maybe more elegant way to achieve this. Thank you.